# How do I insert multiple checkbox values into database?

Tags: php, html

How do I insert multiple checkbox values into database? Here is my code, it workes for the radio buttons where there is only one value, but how do I insert more if I have checkboxes?

PHP CODE:

```
if(isset($_POST['radio']) &&
    isset($_POST['checkbox'])){

    $radio = $_POST['radio'];
    $checkbox= $_POST['checkbox'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO info(radio, checkbox)VALUES ('$radio', '$checkbox')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">2<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3">3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="5">5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="6">6<br>
```

Comment: make your textbox name as array and use a loop when processing the posted values

Answer (score 2):

Html

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">2<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3">3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="5">5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="6">6<br>
```

Php

use a foreach to get all the values of checkboxes

```
//Do the necessary coding and then
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox']))
   foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key=>$value){
      if(trim($value) != ''){
         //Do insertion here
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just one thing to beat in mind, IIRC, `$_POST['checkbox']` won't actually be set if NO checkboxes are checked (they're not sent with the HTTP POST) so it might be worth doing a `!empty($_POST['checkbox'])` type check before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

use php core functions `serialize()` and `unserialize()`

Answer (score 0):

change the names of yours checkboxes to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3">3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="5">5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="6">6<br>
```

on php do it:

```
$radio = $_POST['radio'];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO info(radio, checkbox)';

foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $item){
    $sql .=  "VALUES('$radio', '$item')," ;
}

$sql = trim($sql, ','); //remove the last ',';
//performe all insert at once.
```

avoid to use mysql_* functions, try [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)